# create app from WordPress website

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress

I have a personal website which built on **WordPress**. Now, I'm going to create a simple iOS app for it which enables my readers to read and comment on the posts, view the archive, ... usual stuff.

Since I'm using WordPress and my website is something very common, I was wondering if there are any **free** out of the box toolbox or something for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using WPTouch already?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/

Answer (score 0):

Did you find :

http://ios.wordpress.org

and the whole project:

http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk

I hope it will save you a lot of work ;-)